Iinequality between spectral norm and the sum of induced $L1$ and $L_\infty$ of a matrix
When reading a paper(page 4), I came across a matrix norm inequality.
$$\|A\|_{2} \le \underset{1\le j\le p}{\max}\|A_{j,.}\|_1+\underset{1\le j\le p}{\max}\|A_{.,j}\|_1$$
where $\|A\|_2$ is the spectral norm of the asymmetric square matrix $A$ and $A_{j,.}$($A_{.,j}$) denotes the j-th row(column) of the matrix $A$. Correspondingly，$\|\cdot \|_1$ represents the sum of absolute values ​​of vector elements.
How to prove this inequality?

In the below, denote the induced $p$-norm ($1\le p\le\infty$) of a matrix by $\|\cdot\|_p$. Then
\begin{align*}
\|A\|_2
&=\sqrt{\rho(A^TA)}=\sqrt{\rho(AA^T)}\\
&\le\sqrt{\|AA^T\|_\infty}\quad\text{(spectral radius is infimum of all sub-multiplicative matrix norms)}\\
&\le\sqrt{\|A\|_\infty\|A^T\|_\infty}\quad\text{(induced norms are sub-multiplicative)}\\
&=\sqrt{\|A\|_\infty\|A\|_1}\\
&\le\frac12\left(\|A\|_\infty+\|A\|_1\right)\quad\text{(AM-GM inequality)}\\
&\le\|A\|_\infty+\|A\|_1\\
&=\max_i\|a_{i\ast}\|_1+\max_j\|a_{\ast j}\|_1\quad\text{(equivalent definitions of $\|A\|_\infty$ and $\|A\|_1$)}.\\
\end{align*}
